# Google Form Grid prevent 2 rows from having a same column value

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Grid in my google form, where I want to add a script or an add-on that prevents both rows from having a same answer

[image]

In the above box Restless cannot be MOST and Least both
I want to disable option for LEAST for Restless when MOST is selected
If MOST has one column, LEAST can have any column other than the column taken by MOST
For Example

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution:

Use [GridValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/grid-validation-builder) to limit multiple choice items to one response per column, with the method [requireLimitOneResponsePerColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/grid-validation-builder#requireLimitOneResponsePerColumn()).

#### Code snippet:

For example, to create your item:

```
function createItem() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var gridItem = form.addGridItem();
  gridItem.setTitle('Fill the options below')
    .setRows(['MOST', 'LEAST'])
    .setColumns(['Restless', 'Neighborly', 'Appealing', 'Careful']);
  var gridValidation = FormApp.createGridValidation()
    .setHelpText("Select one item per column.")
    .requireLimitOneResponsePerColumn()
    .build();
  gridItem.setValidation(gridValidation);
}
```

Then, in your form, if you try to select the same column in the two rows:

[image]